# I made form using html and css but label and textbox not coming vertically equal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made form using html and css... I put grid in that but textbox not coming proper vertically when I copy my code in other file then it's coming perfect...

This is my image:

[image]

When i put same code in other file:

[image]

Here is my code:-

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="contact">
        <h1>Contact us!</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
          since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form">
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" class="form-control" />
        <label>Email ID</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Johndoe@gmail.com"
          class="form-control"
        />
        <label>Phone number / Skype ID(if not in Canada)</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="123-456-7890" class="form-control" />
        <label>City</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Select one please"
          class="form-control"
        />
        <label>Attach Resume</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" class="form-control" />
        <button class="btn">Upload Resume</button>
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Type your message..."
        ></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: obviously some CSS issue. now hard to say what exactly without any CSS given. You can find out easily with browser inspector tools though

Comment: but i have not applied any css....just apply same code in two different files

Comment: Kindly use inspect element to determine why the elements on your page are not reflecting as expected.

Comment: It's hard to guess where the bug is without the inspector

Comment: @AnkitJindal I checked everything nothing could be found

Comment: @devanshi with the above information it is hard to depict what is going wrong. Can you try opening your webpage in a different browser?

Comment: I can easily see some bootstrap classes in your code, if you are using third party css library apart from just html and css, then their own css might be affecting your form, as in second image you can see some of the css is gone. debug this with Inspector tool, try to find issues with margin and/or padding.

Comment: @elpidaguy yes correct... i insepect element and there is one css padding left is applied for all input that's why it coming like this.... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing div tag for class="container"

```html
<!-- This is just to load bootstrap css -->
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="contact">
        <h1>Contact us!</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form">
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" class="form-control">
        <label>Email ID</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Johndoe@gmail.com" class="form-control">
        <label>Phone number / Skype ID(if not in Canada)</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="123-456-7890" class="form-control">
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Select one please" class="form-control">
        <label>Attach Resume</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" class="form-control">
        <button class="btn">Upload Resume</button>
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message..."></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have a working example of this, or copy the code snippet and show that it works to align it. You might be on the right track, just provide a bit more robust of an answer and how it fixes the issue (though in this case, it is nearly trivial)

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing your form inputs in div.form-group solves this and makes the form more attractive. Try this

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="contact">
        <h1>Contact us!</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
          ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
          type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Email ID</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Johndoe@gmail.com"
            class="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Phone number / Skype ID(if not in Canada)</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="123-456-7890"
            class="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>City</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Select one please"
            class="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Attach Resume</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="John Doe" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Message</label>
          <textarea
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Type your message..."
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn">Upload Resume</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```